# Which projection, in $L_\infty$ norm or $L_2$ norm, is non-expansion?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, regression, least-squares

I am just wondering which projection is non-expansion? Basically, I am wondering if $F$ is a projection operator then which norm would satisfy the following non-expansion property, where for a given norm $\parallel \cdot \parallel$
$$\parallel FJ_1 - FJ_2\parallel \le \parallel J_1-J_2\parallel$$

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I have no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I updated the question. Hope it is clear now.